# Does NASA use whale oil in the Hubble Telescope?

Tags: astronomy, nasa

The History Channel documentary [*America, the Story of Us*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America%3a_The_Story_of_Us) states that NASA uses whale oil in the Hubble Space Telescope.

Is there any solid evidence to confirm or dispute this claim?

Comment: The History Channel... What a misnomer...

Comment: @System Down Seen anything on The Learning Channel... ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This appears to be a myth that has been repeated in the media. White it is true that [whale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whale_oil) and [sperm oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_oil) have been used historically as lubricants, modern [synthetic replacements](http://www.lubegard.com/lxe.aspx) exist from a variety of manufactures to include the [Nye Lubricants](http://www.nyelubricants.com/index.shtml) that is mentioned in various articles as being a provider to NASA of lubricants.

At least three articles have been written fact checking the story. The first from [Chemical Heritage Magazine](http://www.chemheritage.org/discover/media/magazine/index.aspx) titled "[Whales in Space](http://www.chemheritage.org/discover/media/magazine/articles/31-3-whales-in-space.aspx)" reported the following,

> Speculation about the use of whale oil in NASA’s machines had spread
>   far enough by the late 1990s that the organization’s historians
>   conducted a large-scale internal inquiry. At the time, most
>   speculation focused on whale oil use in space shuttles, not in the
>   Hubble telescope. Bill Barry, NASA’s chief historian, recalls that
>   researchers traced the whale-oil rumors back to Nye Lubricants. “Our
>   Shuttle engineers had a discussion with the chief of engineering at
>   Nye Lubricants and left that conversation convinced that whale-based
>   oils had been ‘out of vogue for a good many years’ and had never been
>   used on the Shuttle.” Case closed.
>
> Since then NASA has conducted additional investigations into its other
>   programs and has found no evidence of whale oil being used. After the
>   History Channel documentary aired, NASA turned to Twitter to refute
>   the recycled claim, quoting Hubble’s astrophysics systems manager: “No
>   whale oil was used in Hubble.” But such pronouncements can’t seem to
>   kill the story.

Some further information on the fact checking of the "Whales in Space" article is [written by the fact checker](http://chemheritage.tumblr.com/post/80687677682/from-the-fact-checker-whales-in-space) who largely attributes the myth to arising out of the book "[The Whale: In Search of the Giants of the Sea](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061976202)" and bad fact checking on the part of its author.

Comment: I believe the synthetic replacements are dolphin technology, given as a "thanks for all the fish".

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I guess it's important to have a porpoise in life.